# JAXB class to JSON conversion using Jackson

Tags: jackson

I have JAXB annotated class which i am trying to convert to JSON using jackson objectMapper. The issue with generated json is jackson is introduction a new property value:"xxx" for XMLValue annotation which is dont value. for example it is generated as below

```
{
  "employeeName":
{
   "value":"ABC"
}
}
```

but i want it as `{"employeeName":"ABC"}` instead

One more thing is while it wraps the arrays i am getting as below in the generated json

```
{
"Employers":{
"Employer":[
{
"name":"ddd"
}
]
}
```

instead i want it as only

```
{"Employer":[{"name":"ddd"}]}
```

Can someone suggest if above two are possible with jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. It might be helpful when you provide your class so you could get a more specific answer which might use annotations. But at least you could write a custom serializer. If you do so you have full control over the produced json.